# Charpit's method: Check answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following question:

> A complete integral of $f=xpq+yp^2-1=0$ obtained by Charpit's method is:
>
> $(a) \ (z+b)^2=4(ax-y)$
>
> $(b) \ (z+b)^2=4(ax+y)$
>
> $(c) \ (z-b)^2=4(ax+y)$
>
> $(d) \  (z+b)^2=4ax+y^2$
>
> where $p=z_x,q=z_y$.

The given answer is $(b)$.

I tried solving this by Charpit's method but couldn't get an answer.
So I decided to see if the given answer satisfies the original equation.

Differentiating $(b)$ with respect to $x$: $$2(z+b)p=4a$$
Differentiating $(b)$ with respect to $y$: $$2(z+b)q=4$$

Substituting this in the original equation: $$\frac{4ax}{(z+b)^2}+\frac{4a^2y}{(z+b)^2}-1\neq0$$

Now, I tried doing the same for all other options and saw that none of them satisfy the original equation.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you please check carefully your task? It seems more likely that $f=xpq+yq^2-1$ is the equation for the given solutions. And what is the difference between b) and c)?

Comment: @LutzL I have written the exact question. And yes, I agree that there is no difference between $(b)$ and $(c)$. Can you please tell me a way to get the complete integral. Using Charpit's method, I got no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the equation were $f=xpq+yq^2−1=0$
the Charpit equations would be ($f_z=0$) 
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
&dx&:&dy&:&dz&:&-dp&:&-dq\\
=&f_p&:&f_q&:&f_pp+f_qq&:&f_x&:&f_y
\\
=&xq&:&xp+2yq&:&2&:&pq&:&q^2
\end{array}
For $q\ne 0$ the last two components integrate to $p=aq$.

The first and the last give $dx:x=-dq:q$ integrating to $qx=c$. Now insert into the equation
$$
1=axq^2+yq^2\iff \frac{x^2}{c^2}=ax+y
$$
and
$$
dz=pdx+qdy=qd(ax+y)=qd\left(\frac{x^2}{c^2}\right)=\frac{2}{c}dx
$$
so that after integration
$$
z+b=2\frac{x}{c}\implies (z+b)^2=4\frac{x^2}{c^2}=4(ax+y)
$$
which is compatible with variants (b) and (c).

---

With the equation as given you get $p^2-q^2=a$ as one invariant of the characteristics, and then $z+b=\frac{2q}{ap}$ and with the original equation
$$
a\left(\frac a2x(z+b)+y\right)=1-\frac{a^2}4(z+b)^2
\\\iff
a^2(z+b+x)^2-a^2x^2+4y=4
$$
which does not look like any of the variants

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it.